# How to bypass authentication on soap web service enpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soapui, soap-client

I have a springboot java project in which i have exposed rest api ednpoints as well as soap api endpoints. Also spring-security is there in my project. But I want security only on rest endpoints and don't want soap endpoints to be authenticated.  I tried adding the endpoint to the WebSecurityConfig in permitAll().  But still soap endpoints are requiring authentication.

How can i bypass this authentication just for soap endpoints ?

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="social.login",havingValue = "false")
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth -> auth
                        
                        .requestMatchers("/ws/register/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()))

                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
           
                return httpSecurity.build();

    }
```

My soap endpoint is localhost:8099/ws/register.

I don't want authentication to be applied on this.

Comment: `/ws/register` is not matching `/ws/registere/**`. Also, a common misconception, that `permitAll` disables security/authentication. You would also need to add `anonymous()` authentication as there still needs to be an `Authentication` object.

Comment: can you please provide some sample code, where the projects have rest endpoints as well as soap endpoints and spring-starter-security is there for rest endpoints and want to skip authentication for soap endpoints.

Comment: No and I already gave you answers in the previous comments. Your URL doesn't match and you don't have anonymous authentication enabled.

Comment: @M.Deinum  

I tried using this bean 

`    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer ignoringCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/ws/**");
    }`

Got logs like this
o.s.s.c.a.web.builders.WebSecurity       : You are asking Spring Security to ignore Mvc [pattern='/ws/**']. This is not recommended -- please use permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead.
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will not secure Mvc [pattern='/ws/**']


But still when hitting get 401

Comment: Don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable. You also have a custom filter is that implemented correctly? As mentioned, just provide this pattern to your `permitAll` instead of ignoring all security.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:soapui]?

Comment: my endpoint is of soap web service that's why it's not working i guess. Both are different httpSecurity is not able to trace the request.